# After getting weight from train/answer, How can I predict the future vaue?

Tags: python, tensorflow

It might be the tensorflow beginner question.

I have a combination `trainX(training)` and `trainY(answer)`, `testX` and `testY` and single `furtureX`(to predict futureY)

then I got the weight as `w_h`,`b_h`,`w`,`b`

```
w_h = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([companys,n_hidden],stddev=0.001))
b_h = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_hidden]))

w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden,1],stddev=0.001)) 
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,companys]) # change dimensions to 2 -> 10
t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,1])

h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,w_h) + b_h)
y = tf.matmul(h,w) + b

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y,labels=t))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.to_float(tf.greater(y,0.5)),t)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for epoch in range(20000):
    sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={
        x: trainX,
        t: trainY
    })
    if epoch % 1000  == 0:
        trainAcc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: trainX, t: trainY})
        testAcc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: testX, t: testY})
        print ("accuracy at %s   train:%.3f  test:%.3f" % (epoch, trainAcc,testAcc))

#successfully get the final `weight` here

bIn = sess.run(b)
wIn = sess.run(w)
bHide = sess.run(b_h)
wHide = sess.run(w_h)
pprint(bIn)
pprint(wIn)
pprint(bHide)
pprint(wHide)

#I want to get the final data from `futureX`
```

Now, with the final 'weight', I want to predict future from the `futureX`.

What kind of function should I use???

I read many books for beginners and understand how to put train and test data, but 
can't find the way to predict the future..

Comment: Call: `sess.run(tf.sigmoid(y), feed_dict={x: futureX})`

Comment: FutureX should be same as trainX, The error is because of batch size =1, feed, np.reshape(futureX, [1,-1]) this will convert it to (1, 52) instead of (52). trainX should work as it was working for prediction, check the shape before you are feeding it.

Comment: Sorry, it was my misunderstanding, it works with trainX correctly. I think I should get the final goal with your help. thank you very much